# How to change menu item dynamically/instantly?

Tags: java, android, android-menu

I have a refresh button on action bar for 3 activities. These 3 activities extended from `BaseActivity`. So that provides me to write `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) { //... }` method for once.

When user clicks it, I want to change the icon to `refreshing` icon.

I can handle click and refresh operations and also changing the icon but cannot handle change icon back when my operation completes.

What is the best way to know when a method (which located in activity which extends from `BaseActivity`) has finished its job? Do I have to use `interface` to handle it on `BaseActivity`'s `onOptionsItemSelected()` method?

Answer (score 0):

When you want to change the icon, call `invalidateOptionsMenu()` (this will trigger `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` to be called) and add some logic to change the icon within `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` e.g.

```
@Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.id.menu, menu);
    if(isRefreshing()){
      menu.findItem(R.id.refresh).setIcon(R.drawable.refreshing);
    }else{
      menu.findItem(R.id.refresh).setIcon(R.drawable.refresh);
    }
  }
```

The above code will inflate the menu resource `R.id.menu` and change the icon depending on the result of `isRefreshing()`.

Comment: That makes sense, I may have missed because of sleeplessness. Anyway, there is a little problem here. When I call invalidateOptionsMenu() in my activity, it does not trigger onCreateOptionsMenu() method. What do I missing?

Comment: Are you on API version 11 or above?

Comment: Yes, I am on API version 17.